# Show that $(A \oplus B)^n = A^n \oplus B^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So the question is to prove that $(A \oplus B)^n = A^n \oplus B^n$, for all $A \in M_{p,p}$ and $B \in M_{q,q}$. I could sort of see how this would work out, but I'm struggling to prove rigorously. I thought this would be a well-known property, tried to look for proofs on the Internet but no luck. Would be appreciated if someone could help or point me to the right website.

Comment: you should give more information, what are A and B?

Comment: the symbol $\oplus$ stands for direct sum, I guess. Is this a direct sum of rings, vector spaces, what's going on, exactly? Meanings of symbols are not set in stone, don't ever assume that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First show that $$(A_1 \oplus B_1)(A_2 \oplus B_2) = (A_1A_2) \oplus (B_1B_2)$$ for all $A_1,A_2 \in M_{p,p}$ and $B_1,B_2 \in M_{q,q}$.  This depends on your precise definition of the $\oplus$ of two matrices, so I can't show it here.  For instance, if you define it by its action on the direct sum of spaces $\mathbb{R}^p \oplus \mathbb{R}^q,$ then it's basically trivial, while if you define it as a block matrix, it may require you to go through the product using the definition of matrix multiplication.

Anyway, once you have that, you can use induction to finish up.  The case of $n=1$ is obvious, while the inductive step is
$$\begin{align*}
(A \oplus B)^n &= (A \oplus B)^{n-1} (A \oplus B) \\ &= (A^{n-1} \oplus B^{n-1})(A \oplus B) \\ &= (A^{n-1}A) \oplus (B^{n-1}B) \\ &= A^n \oplus B^n
\end{align*}$$
where the third equality (second from last) is where we have to use the product formula above.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot!